# NodeJS MongoDB Add to Array of Subdocuments

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, subdocument

So I'm working on my login system, using Mongo for my backend. I want to be able to have multiple users on one account so I'm developing a route to deal with this. I have a model for my accounts and a schema for my users. This is how I am trying to create a user currently:

```
router.post('/CreateUser', async(req, res) =>{
    try{

        const acc = await Account.findOne({"Email": req.body.Email});
        if(!acc) throw Error('Email not found');
        var newUser = new User(req.body.User); 
        acc.Users.push(newUser);
        res.status(200).send({success:true});

    }
    catch(err){
        res.status(400).send({msg:err.toString(),success:false});

    }
});
```

Here is my UserSchema:

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
    // Name of the user
    Username:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
        unique:true
    },
    // PIN for each user
    PIN:{
        type:Number,
        require:true
    }

});

module.exports = UserSchema;
```

My Account Model:

```
const User = require('../Models/UserData');

const AccountSchema = new Schema({
    // Email linked to this account
    Email:{
        type:String,
        unique:true,
        required:true,
        index:true
    },
    // Password for the account
    Password:{
        type : String,
        required : true
    },
    // Users on this account
    Users:{
        type:[User],
        required:true
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Account', AccountSchema);
```

It returns `success:true`, but the only change I see in the database is an entirely new collection that is completely empty. I also need to check if the username already exists, but one step at a time.

Edit: This is body that I'm using for the POST request:

```
{
    "Email":"Paul@test.com",
    "User":
    {
        "Username":"56",
        "PIN":4659
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Save the updated record to DB `acc.save` if you want to save record to user model as well call `user.save`

```
router.post('/CreateUser', async(req, res) =>{
    try{

        const acc = await Account.findOne({"Email": req.body.Email});
        if(!acc) throw Error('Email not found');
        var newUser = new User(req.body.User);
        acc.Users.push(newUser);
        const saveAccount = await acc.save(); // SAVE Account
        const saveUser = await newUser.save(); // SAVE User


    }
    catch(err){
        res.status(400).send({msg:err.toString(),success:false});

    }
});
```